# Как лучше реализовать запрос на EF6 c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, реализация

Есть запрос на вставку:

```
public void AddPerson(string Name)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var query = new Person()
        {
            PersonName = Name
        };

    context.Persons.Add(query);
    context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Т. е. при каждом вызове метода будет создан новый экземпляр класса DbContext и, следовательно, будет создано новое подключение к базе. Мне кажется, что это не лучшая реализация. Посоветуйте, как лучше реализовать запрос.

Comment: Не факт что будет создано новое, есть пул подключений для таких случаев. Но это поведение зависит от настроек.

Comment: Если вы используете EF 6, то почему в метках стоит EF Core.

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? Во многих из них по умолчанию включен пул соединений. В других его можно включить вручную.

Comment: В EF Core есть [DbContext pooling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant)

Comment: Спасибо за советы, буду копать в сторону connection pool